# A better Python package manager

Tags: python, packaging

Broadly speaking, I'm looking for something that behaves much more like `npm` or `yarn`, surely there must be something better than `pip`!

I know that questions should be clear cut and not invite opinionated answers, so here are a list of requirements I have for what I consider a better package manager (lets call it `ppm`):

- `ppm` must be able to access the PyPi repository
- `ppm` must automatically add installed packages to a "package" file.
- It must be possible for someone else to install all the same packages as me given said "package" file.
- It should be possible to easily integrate the dependencies listed in this "package" file into the `setup.py` file so that it easy to then publish the code to PyPi.
- `ppm` should support running custom scripts for example I should be able to type:

```
>>> ppm run tests
```

and have it run the (less than memorable) command:

```
>>> python -m unittest discover -s <test_folder> -p '*_test.py'
```

or whatever specific test, run, build or packaging command is needed.

---

So what package managers exist that meet some or all of my requiments? Or what workarounds are available to me that would meet my requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Pipenv is in my opinion close to something like npm. Although, I am not sure if it can run scripts. https://github.com/pypa/pipenv

Edit: Looks like it can run [custom scripts](https://dev.to/elanorigby/i-love-pipenvs-custom-script-shortcuts-156k), tests ect.

Comment: I was worried someone would recommend `pipenv`. I have previously found it to be incredibly buggy. I gave it second chance today, I still can't say I'm impressed, it's failing to install packages and I'm not having much luck googling the errors. 
But thanks all the same for your answer, I will persevere with `pipenv` for a little longer.

Comment: OK so uninstalling pyenv and pipenv, rebooting and installing them again (remembering the `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` at the bottom of my `.bash_profile`) has resolved my ungooglable bugs.

Comment: @Resonance just wondering. Why pyenv and pipenv together? Wouldn't one of them do the trick?

Comment: Pipenv uses pyenv to create venvs. Pyenv on its own it not a package manager. And pipenv on its on is not able to create venvs. See the duplicate question for more info.

Comment: Thanks, for the clarification.